# Combined csv via cmd

Tags: csv, cmd, merge

I'm currently working on a way to combine 3 csv files and have the following script to do so:

### Script

```
@echo off

ECHO Set working directory
pushd %~dp0

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set cnt=1

for %%i in (*.csv) do (
 if !cnt!==1 (
 for /f "delims=" %%j in ('type "%%i"') do echo %%j >> combined.csv
      ) else if %%i NEQ combined.csv (
  for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%j in ('type "%%i"') do echo %%j >>            combined.csv
  )
REM increment count by 1
  set /a cnt+=1
)'
```

This works like a charm and also strips the header of the other 2 csv files in the working dir.

The script now outputs *combined.csv*, which is nice but I would like the script to output NL2 **ddmmyyyy.csv**.

The issue I have and can't seem to figure out is how to make the name of the output file incremental and date-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code can parse the date elements from the DATE variable. The format of the date will vary based on locale. Mine is set to YYYY-MM-DD, but yours may be different.

```
M:>echo %DATE%
2016-01-27

 8:23:58.28 \\SWPDCENDWXTK01\D$  M:\DW_Devl\Paul\phs_dmx_config\bin
M:>SET FNDATE=%DATE:~8,2%%DATE:~5,2%%DATE:~0,4%

 8:24:08.54 \\SWPDCENDWXTK01\D$  M:\DW_Devl\Paul\phs_dmx_config\bin
M:>ECHO %FNDATE%
27012016
```

Inside the loop, set a variable and use it for the output.

```
SET COMBO_FILENAME=NL!cnt!%FNDATE%.csv
ECHO %%j >>!COMBO_FILENAME!
```

Comment: Cheers Liturgist, this helped me fix the issue.